# find main directory name which doesn't contains file in sub directory

Tags: linux, shell, command

I have three folders as `test1, test2,test3`. under these three folders i have two folders as common `dir1,dir2` . Each of the above three parent folders will have these two as sub folders. I will have one text file (`file.txt`) in `dir1` in any one of the parent directory.

Is there a find or grep single line command to get the parent directory name as output if `file.txt` doesn't exists in `dir1` sub folder?

Example:

`ls test1`
`o/p: dir1, dir2`

`ls test2`
`o/p: dir1/file.txt,dir2`

`ls test3`
`o/p: dir1/file.txt,dir2`

i need a command which gives `test1` as output

Comment: are your sure `ls test2` gives this output `dir1/file.txt,dir2` ? ls does not display files in subfolders

Comment: i have just mentioned it for understanding the directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

something like below should do what you need :

```
for f in test*/dir1/ 
do 
  [[ $(find "$f" -name "file.txt") ]] || echo `dirname "$f"`  
done
```